# Powershell - Scheduled Tasks, language independence, Win 7+

Tags: powershell, internationalization, scheduled-tasks

I know there has to be an easy solution to this but I have been searching for two days now with no luck.

**Basic goal:**
I want to query (and set) the state of `Scheduled Defrag` using `PowerShell`

Limitations:  Must be able to work when run with the system set to any language, Must  not require installing any additional software, packs, etc (ie clean system), Must be able to run on any system Windows 7+ (ideally even earlier)

**Issues:**

1. I can get the state using `'schtasks /query /TN
   '\Microsoft\Windows\Defrag\ScheduledDefrag''` but this is **(a)**
   directory language dependent, and more importantly **(b)** returns
   everything as  a string of some sort, meaning state is something
   like `'Disabled'`.. in English.  But every language returns its own
   word for 'Disabled', in its own character code, meaning hard-coding
   over a hundred languages x the number of options
2. `Windows 7` does not recognize `Get-ScheduledTask` (seems to be
   Win8+), even if it did not sure how to query 'Disabled' as a state
   without using the actual word

I have to be missing something very basic but all I am finding are suggestions to install  Powershell packs, and responses dealing specifically with English.  Any suggestions?

Comment: As an aside, I tried seeing about just changing the local culture as per: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583235.aspx  - great solution, works well for built in stuff like get-date, but looks like 'Enabled' and 'Disabled' and such do not get converted. (Neither do directories but I did not expect them to be,  fortunately the one needed  for this is in English on all systems)

Comment: Have you tried the `/xml` flag on `schtasks`?  It writes out the results in xml, which is intended to be consumed by code, so I *assume* (but haven't tested) that the output should be independent of the system language.

Comment: Rather than parsing the output of `schtasks`, try the `Schedule.Service` COM object. See http://jon.netdork.net/2011/03/08/powershell-and-exporting-windows-scheduled-tasks/

Comment: +1 for `Schedule.Service`. Also take a look at Microsoft's [scripting examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384006) and of course the [object reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383607).

Comment: Perfect!! Its not a direct match between .State (Disabled/Ready) and the xml result (which seems to be <enabled>true/false</enabled> but it is close enough that I have something to parse!  Thank you! :)

Comment: The xml solution seems the most approachable at the moment, but I will certainly look over the others.  The scripting examples from MS do not help too much since they focus on the English output (which is easy enough to get but language dependent, unless I am still missing something critical about this use) - I will look deeper into Schedule.Service asap